# Partial VIEW not rendering MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a VIEW as such :

```
@model grepTMVC.Models.TAgentStatHeaderModelList

@{
    if (ViewBag.userTypeID == null)
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_InitLayout.cshtml";

    }
    else if (ViewBag.userTypeID == "TA")
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_TALayout.cshtml";
    }
    else if (ViewBag.userTypeID == "TR")
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_TRLayout.cshtml";
    }
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/media/js/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.rating.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.MetaData.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.form.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.rating.pack.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.rating.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "B On Ts";
}

@section SideBar1 {
<ul>
      <li><a href="#">Section page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Section page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Section page 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Section page 4</a></li>
</ul>
}

@section SideBar2 {
<h3>
    Aside heading
</h3>
Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan.
}

@{
    if (ViewBag.userName != null)
    {
        <div align="right"><font color="#000000" size="2">User: @ViewBag.userName  is logged in</font></div>
    }
}

@{
    if (ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <p><font color="red" size="2">@ViewBag.Message </font></p>
    }
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<fieldset>
    <div>
        @{ if (ViewBag.frompage == "_MyTBDetailTA" || ViewBag.frompage == "_OtherTBDetailTA")
           {
                @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "MyTBHeaderTA", "", new { style = "font-family:Verdana;font-size:13px" })
           }
           else
           {
                @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "AllTHeaderTR", "", new { style = "font-family:Verdana;font-size:13px" })
           }

           TempData["l_frompage"] = ViewBag.frompage;
         }
    </div>
    <br />    

    <legend>Agent Stats</legend>
    <br />
    <div id="grid">
    @{      Html.Grid(Model).Columns(column =>
            {
                column.For(c => c.providerID).Named("T Agent").HeaderAttributes(@class => "gridheader");
                column.For(c => c.noOfB).Named("No. Of B").HeaderAttributes(@class => "gridheader");
                column.For(c => c.noOfRates).Named("No. Of Rates").HeaderAttributes(@class => "gridheader");
                column.Custom(@<div>
                @{
                    if (@item.avgUserRate > 0 && @item.avgUserRate <= 0.25M)
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "0.25" name="@item.rateCount" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" title="Very Poor"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "0.25" name="@item.rateCount" disabled="disabled" title="Very Poor"/>
                    }

                    if (@item.avgUserRate > 0.25M && @item.avgUserRate <= 0.5M)
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "0.5" name="@item.rateCount" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" title="Very Poor"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "0.5" name="@item.rateCount"  disabled="disabled" title="Very Poor"/>
                    }

                    if (@item.avgUserRate > 0.5M && @item.avgUserRate <= 0.75M)
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "0.75" name="@item.rateCount" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" title="Very Poor"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "0.75" name="@item.rateCount" disabled="disabled" title="Very Poor"/>
                    }

                    if (@item.avgUserRate > 0.75M && @item.avgUserRate <= 1M)
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "1" name="@item.rateCount" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"  title="Very Poor"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "1" name="@item.rateCount" disabled="disabled" title="Very Poor"/>
                    }

                    if (@item.avgUserRate > 1M && @item.avgUserRate <= 1.25M)
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "1.25" name="@item.rateCount" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" title="Very Poor"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "1.25" name="@item.rateCount" disabled="disabled" title="Very Poor"/>
                    }

                    if (@item.avgUserRate > 1.25M && @item.avgUserRate <= 1.5M)
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "1.5" name="@item.rateCount" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" title="Poor"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "1.5" name="@item.rateCount" disabled="disabled" title="Poor"/>
                    }

                    if (@item.avgUserRate > 1.5M && @item.avgUserRate <= 1.75M)
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "1.75" name="@item.rateCount" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" title="Poor"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "1.75" name="@item.rateCount" disabled="disabled" title="Poor"/>
                    }

                    if (@item.avgUserRate > 1.75M && @item.avgUserRate <= 2M)
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "2" name="@item.rateCount" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" title="Poor"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "2" name="@item.rateCount" disabled="disabled" title="Poor"/>
                    }

                    if (@item.avgUserRate > 2 && @item.avgUserRate <= 2.25M)
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "2.25" name="@item.rateCount" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" title="Poor"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "2.25" name="@item.rateCount" disabled="disabled" title="Poor"/>
                    }

                    if (@item.avgUserRate > 2.25M && @item.avgUserRate <= 2.5M)
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "2.5" name="@item.rateCount" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" title="Satisfactory"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "2.5" name="@item.rateCount" title="Satisfactory"/>
                    }

                    if (@item.avgUserRate > 2.5M && @item.avgUserRate <= 2.75M)
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "2.75" name="@item.rateCount" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" title="Satisfactory"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "2.75" name="@item.rateCount" disabled="disabled" title="Satisfactory"/>
                    }

                    if (@item.avgUserRate > 2.75M && @item.avgUserRate <= 3M)
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "3" name="@item.rateCount" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" title="Satisfactory"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "3" name="@item.rateCount" disabled="disabled" title="Satisfactory"/>
                    }

                    if (@item.avgUserRate > 3M && @item.avgUserRate <= 3.25M)
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "3.25" name="@item.rateCount" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"  title="Satisfactory"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "3.25" name="@item.rateCount" title="Satisfactory"/>
                    }

                    if (@item.avgUserRate > 3.25M && @item.avgUserRate <= 3.5M)
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "3.5" name="@item.rateCount" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" title="Good"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "3.5" name="@item.rateCount" disabled="disabled" title="Good"/>
                    }

                    if (@item.avgUserRate > 3.5M && @item.avgUserRate <= 3.75M)
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "3.75" name="@item.rateCount" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" title="Good"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "3.75" name="@item.rateCount" disabled="disabled" title="Good"/>
                    }

                    if (@item.avgUserRate > 3.75M && @item.avgUserRate <= 4M)
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "4" name="@item.rateCount" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" title="Good"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "4" name="@item.rateCount" disabled="disabled" title="Good"/>
                    }

                    if (@item.avgUserRate > 4M && @item.avgUserRate <= 4.25M)
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "4.25" name="@item.rateCount" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" title="Good"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "4.25" name="@item.rateCount" disabled="disabled" title="Good"/>
                    }

                    if (@item.avgUserRate > 4.25M && @item.avgUserRate <= 4.5M)
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "4.5" name="@item.rateCount" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" title="Excellent"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "4.5" name="@item.rateCount" disabled="disabled" title="Excellent"/>
                    }

                    if (@item.avgUserRate > 4.5M && @item.avgUserRate <= 4.75M)
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "4.75" name="@item.rateCount" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" title="Excellent"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "4.75" name="@item.rateCount" disabled="disabled" title="Excellent"/>
                    }

                    if (@item.avgUserRate > 4.75M && @item.avgUserRate <= 5M)
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "5" name="@item.rateCount" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" title="Excellent"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" value = "5" name="@item.rateCount" disabled="disabled" title="Excellent"/>
                    }
                }

                </div>).Named("Average Rate").HeaderAttributes(@class => "gridheader").Attributes(style => "width:40%");                
            }).Render();
    }
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {    
        //Placing this prior to your .get() call will ensure the request is not cached
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $('#grid tbody tr').on('hover', function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('clickable');
        }).on('click', function () {
            var self = this;
            $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/T/ViewAgentsDetailTR",
                        data: { providerID: $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text()
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#wrapper').html(data);
                            $(self).off('click');
                        }
                    });
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var oTable = $(".grid").dataTable({
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                "bDestroy": true,
                "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
                "aoColumnDefs": [{ 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [3]}]
            }).after('<br />');
        });
    });
</script>
</fieldset>
}
```

This view calls a POST method to my controller, which calls a stored procedure. When in debug mode, i do see the model being populated as per below:

```
try
  {
      MySqlDataReader rdr1 = command1.ExecuteReader();

      TAgentStatHeaderModelList agentStatModList = new TAgentStatHeaderModelList();                    

      int l_rate = 1;

      while (rdr1.Read())
      {
          var model = new TAgentStatHeaderModel();

          model.travelDest = rdr1["travelDest"].ToString();
          model.userRate = Convert.ToInt32(rdr1["userRate"]);
          model.rateCount = l_rate++;
          model.comments = rdr1["vComments"].ToString();

          agentStatModList.Add(model);
      }                    
      rdr1.Close();                    

      dbcontroller1.conn.Close();

      return PartialView("_ViewAgentsDetailTR", agentStatModList);
  }
```

But it never goes into my PartialVIEW, even though in my controller, i see it reaches that point having the model correctly showing the data

My partialView is defined as such :

```
@model IEnumerable<grepTMVC.Models.TravelAgentStatHeaderModel>

@{
    if (ViewBag.userTypeID == null)
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_InitLayout.cshtml";

    }
    else if (ViewBag.userTypeID == "TA")
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_TAPartialLayout.cshtml";
    }
    else if (ViewBag.userTypeID == "TR")
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_TRPartialLayout.cshtml";
    }
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@section SideBar1 {
<ul>
      <li><a href="#">Section page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Section page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Section page 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Section page 4</a></li>
</ul>
}

@section SideBar2 {
<h3>
    Aside heading
</h3>
Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan.
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div align="right"><font color="#000000" size="2">User: @ViewBag.userName  is logged in</font></div>

    <fieldset>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div>
            @{
                 @Html.ActionLink("Back to list", "ViewAgentsHeaderTR", "T", new { style = "font-family:Verdana;font-size:13px" })
            }
            </div>
        }

        <br />

        <legend>Detail Ratings</legend>

        <table class="tabledetail">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <th class="thdetail">
                    TD
                </th>
                <td class="tddetail">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tD)
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th class="thdetail">
                    Comments
                </th>
                <td class="tddetail">
                <div style="height: 100px; width:700px; overflow: hidden">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.comments)
                </div>
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
        </table>
    </fieldset>
    <br />
}
```

Ok,

I have removed the try/catch block and changed the PartialView to have :
    @model grepTMVC.Models.TAgentStatHeaderModelList

My Model is such : 
    public class TAgentStatHeaderModel
    {
       public Int64 providerID { get; set; }

```
   public Decimal avgUserRate { get; set; }

   public Int32 noOfRates { get; set; }

   public int rateCount { get; set; }

   public int userRate { get; set; }

   public string comments { get; set; }    
}

public class TAgentStatHeaderModelList : List<TAgentStatHeaderModel>
{
}
```

However, nothing has changed. I dont see an error message. When i click on the row of my grid, nothing happens. in debug mode, it goes through my stored procedure and adds to the model, 5 rows. Thereafter, it tries to call the PartialView, but it doesnt display

Comment: Maybe get rid of try/catch in case the view is throwing exception that you aren't seeing.  Also I notice you are passing `TAgentStatHeaderModelList` to a view that expecteds `IEnumerable<grepTMVC.Models.TravelAgentStatHeaderModel>` depending on whether it really implements that interface, it might be throwing a "expcted model of type" exception in the view.

Comment: I think you're mistaking what a partial view is and just a "View"  you do not use a Layout with a PartialView, that would be a view.  From the controller you return a view - you can return a partial view , in the case that the action is being called by ajax , and you just want to return a table  or data or something like that , ut it doesn't seem like that is what you are doing.  You want a View , a View can have a Layout , and child partial views

Comment: you have multiple Section's in a partial View , the sections go in the view , and the partial Views would be the Side Bar and stuff like that ,   anything that is re-usable.

Comment: I will remove the try/catch and see if there is an error. Thanks for that

Comment: another bit of advice you copied and pasted that input like 20 times , why don't you add a property to the viewModel , something like InputValue,  then if avg >= & <= .... set the Input value to something ,   then you would just write the input once and get all that logic out of the view

Comment: @Scott, thanks for the response. Th reason i used _PartialLayout was because my partialViews were giving me alot of pain in terms of formatting in my browser. My tables (written in HTML) were going off the page,not aligning against the _layouts defined in my VIEWS. I used these _PartialLayouts as a workaround. I'm not sure if you have come across layout issues wrt to PartialViews, but if you have, please let me know and what the solution is. Thanks again,